# Can OpenFileDialog and SaveFileDialog have different InitialDirectory values

Tags: c#, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I have two buttons on a Windows Form, one called `Browse` and the other Called `Change Location`.

I would like to be able to set the `InitialDirectory` value to be different for each of these buttons.

The reason for this is that the `Browse` button opens images to display on screen and the `Change Location` saves a text file to the selected location. I wish for these folders to be different.

I have provided code below for what I have so far:

```
//Code for the browse button
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Image Files To Be Displayed";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"..\..\pigeonImages\";
        // Set filter options and filter index.
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files|*.png;*.jpeg;*.gif|All Files|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.FileName = String.Empty;
        //Allow for multiple files to be selected
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

        // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Create a stream which points to the open file
            Stream openFileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
            //Create a reader
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileStream);
            //Read the contents of the stream
            string shortenedFilenames = String.Empty;
            StringBuilder totalFiles = new StringBuilder();
            //to get just one filename use openDialog1.FileName
            //to get multiple filenames use openDialog1.FileNames
            foreach(string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
            {
                shortenedFilenames = file.Substring(openFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);
                totalFiles.Append(shortenedFilenames).Append(", ");
            }
            string totalFilesResult = totalFiles.ToString();
            totalFilesResult = totalFilesResult.TrimEnd(' ');
            totalFilesResult = totalFilesResult.TrimEnd(',');
            tbResults.Text = totalFilesResult;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fileStream -> " + totalFilesResult);

            //Close the reader
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}


//Code for the Change Location button
private void saveLocationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog saveTextDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        saveTextDialog.Title = "Save File In Correct Folder!";
        saveTextDialog.InitialDirectory = @"..\..\testScores\";

        tbSaveLocation.BackColor = Color.White;
        tbSaveLocation.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        saveTextDialog.Filter = "Text Files | *.txt";
        saveTextDialog.DefaultExt = "txt";

        saveResult = saveTextDialog.ShowDialog();


        if (saveResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream saveFileStream = saveTextDialog.OpenFile();
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileStream))
            {
                writer.Write("");
                writer.Flush();
                //writer.Close();
            }
        }
        tbSaveLocation.Text = String.Format("testScores/{0}/{0}.txt", birdIdString);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

I have set a different `InitialDirectory` value in each method.
I have also used the string without the @symbol and changed the \'s to /'s but this still does not work.

It seems that no matter which button I click on, the `pigeonImages` folder always displays.
I have also tried a variation of `RestoreDirectory` in each method and in both methods and in neither method but this does not work either.

Thanks in advance.

---

When I send the `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory` to the console, I get this as output:

`C:\path\to\my\program\here\bin\Debug\..\..\pigeonImages\`

I always thought that typing `..\` would take you up a folder level.
I am used to writing code on a Mac, does Windows have a different way to go up a folder?

Comment: Have you tried setting .InitialDirectory to a full path, instead of relative path, for both the folders.

Comment: @WhoIsRich I would but I plan on using this program on many computers. The folders will be always with this program, but not necessarily in the same place on each computers hard drive

Comment: Then use var folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); to get where the program is being run and append to it.

Comment: Put a breakpoint before `ShowDialog` and add a watch expression `Directory.Exists(@"..\..\pigeonImages")`. And also check if the dialog has set the initial path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is beacuse of ....\

Do the following instead.

create a var so that you only need to call your applications current location once

```
//needed namespaces
using System.Reflections
using System.IO;

private string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

now in your buttons

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(appDir, "dir1", "dir2");
```

Comment: just to make sure, my button should read:

`openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = 
Path.Combine(appDir, @"..\..\pigeonImages\");`

Comment: You don't want to use ..\.. in your code appDir will get you the location of your application then use the directory names to your images.

Comment: You are a legend. Both buttons now open separate folders, and the folders that they should open. Also +1 for including `System.Reflection` I couldn't get @WhoIsRich's path to work before.